# Error connecting bosh CLI to the VM with virtualbox: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, curl, virtualbox, cf-bosh

I'm following the bosh quick-start to getting started with bosh.
I have created the environment with the command bosh create-env (http://mariash.github.io/learn-bosh/#setup_bosh_environment) and everything seems fine.
The problem is when I try to execute the next command to point the CLI to the VM (http://mariash.github.io/learn-bosh/#log_in) because I run into following error:

Fetching info:
  Performing request GET 'https://192.168.50.6:25555/info':
    Performing GET request:
      Retry: Get https://192.168.50.6:25555/info: dial tcp 192.168.50.6:25555: getsockopt: connection refused

Exit code 1

I tried to ping 192.168.50.6 and this works fine. But I can't curl http(s)://192.168.50.6:25555/info because of: "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.50.6 port 25555: Connection refused"

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I also tried to disable the ufw with command "sudo disable ufw" since I thought that could solve the problem, but nothing has changed.

bosh --version: version 2.0.44-21639e8-2017-10-17T18:49:44Z
Virtual Box Version: 5.2.0 r118431 (Qt5.6.1)

bosh-cli-2.0.44-linux-amd64 installed from https://bosh.io/docs/cli-v2#install.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this problem ?

Comment: Probably no process is running on the port 25555

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `bosh create-env` command didn't actually create a BOSH director. You can try running the same create-env command again; if you already have a BOSH director it will just print "No deployment, stemcell or release changes. Skipping deploy. Succeeded" at the end of its output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I solved it yesterday and the problem was that the file cpi.yml under bosh/virtualbox/sets 4 Gb ram to the vm as standard but my notebook has 4 Gb ram in total, so changing the configuration file solved the Problem. Virtual box stopped the vm after creation and a Restart from virtualbox with less ram did not solve the problem. The only way was changing this cpi.yml and run the create-env again.

Comment: Glad I could help!